# mysql fetching only one field

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an easy method to extract only one field. For instance:

```
$sql = "SELECT field1 FROM table";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$field1 = $arr['field1'];
```

My feeling says this could be done much easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [mysql_result()](http://uk.php.net/mysql_result).

> string mysql_result  ( resource $result  , int $row  [, mixed $field= 0  ] )
> Retrieves the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set.

Comment: Ah I already thought the guys at the mySQL company should have made an easier way to do this.

Comment: `This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.` http://php.net/mysql_result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$sql = "SELECT field1 FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$field1 = mysql_fetch_object($result)->field1;
```

Comment: If a method returns an array or object you cannot access it's members at the same time you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$field1 = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT field1 FROM table"))->field1;
```

Comment: Hmm this isn't very pretty... Those nested thingy's aren't very good for the readability of the code!